# Locale.setDefault affecting Locale.getDefault.getCountry

Tags: java

The output of the following code

```
Locale.setDefault(new Locale("fr"));
System.out.println("Start");
System.out.println(Locale.getDefault().getCountry());
System.out.println("End");
```

is

```
Start

End
```

whereas the output of this code

```
//Locale.setDefault(new Locale("fr"));
System.out.println("Start");
System.out.println(Locale.getDefault().getCountry());
System.out.println("End");
```

is

```
Start
US
End
```

I'm curious why the output of the first code block which changes the default language setting to French results in
an empty string being produced as the output for Locale.getDefault().getCountry()

Comment: `new Locale("fr")` specifies a `Locale` with just the language french but not the country. Try `new Locale("fr_fr")` instead.

Comment: @dan1st the output is still the same with Locale("fr_fr")

Comment: Actually, in this case, you should just use [`Locale.FRANCE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#FRANCE).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to documentation:

> A `java.util.Locale` is a lightweight object that contains only a few important members:
>
> - A language code
> - An optional country or region code
> - An optional variant code

When you create instance of class `Locale` with your constructor, you create a locale with french language and without country or variant specified.

Next you pass Locale you had created to `setDefault` method. So since then you have default locale with french language and no country or variant.

`Locale.setDefault` does not allow you to set only default language. You always set whole Locale object.

To solve your problem you can first get country code from default locale and then create Locale with French language and default country:

```
String defaultCountryCode = Locale.getDefault().getCountry();
Locale.setDefault(new Locale("fr", defaultCountryCode));
System.out.println("Start");
System.out.println(Locale.getDefault().getCountry());
System.out.println("End");
```

and you will get

```
Start
US
End
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the country code as well e.g. `new Locale("fr", "FR")`. It's important because the same language can be spoken in multiple countries e.g. French is spoken in many countries.

```
import java.util.Locale;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Locale.setDefault(new Locale("fr", "FR"));
        System.out.println("Start");
        System.out.println(Locale.getDefault().getCountry());
        System.out.println(Locale.getDefault().getDisplayCountry());
        System.out.println("End");
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Start
FR
France
End
```

Check the tutorial, [**Creating a Locale**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/locale/create.html) to learn more about it.

Your second code snippet outputs the name of the country because it is fetching this information from your default system settings.

Comment: Is there any way to change only the language setting without the country as well?

Comment: @apthewiz - A language can be spoken in multiple countries e.g. French is spoken in many countries. How will the system know which country you mean?

Comment: There are two different Locale.setDefault method formats, one of them has the format of setDefault(Locale newLocale) and the other format takes two parameters and has the format setDefault(Category category, Locale newLocale). I'm trying to implement the former.